# Using spl_autoload_register with classes that require an argument upon instantiation

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

I'm trying to use spl_autoload_register() to automatically require my files for me. Unfortunately one of my classes requires an argument upon instantiation...eg:

```
$foo = new foo('foo');
```

Is there any way to pass an argument to a classes __construct() method with spl_autoload_register()?

Comment: spl_autoload_register works different to __autoload which might be better choice for you, seeing you only want to include files that contain classes you want to instantiate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your autoloader should be responsible for requiring the correct files, not instantiating object(s). Perhaps you could post your autoloader?

Comment: Yepppp...I'll just use my half-asleep brain to explain this one ;)

Answer (score 0):

spl_autoload_register only need handle the including of files. After a class file is included by the registered function, php will then check again if your class name, in your case foo, exists. This allows you instantiate your classes normally, passing whatever parameter list the class normally would expect.